# How to solve the error Using the AjaxCallHelper write methods outside of an AjaxCall is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I've searched this error in all google results, but I can't find a solution.

I have this WebForm:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="-.-.-.LoTest" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajax" Namespace="MagicAjax.UI.Controls" Assembly="MagicAjax" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ajax:AjaxPanel ID="ajaxLG" runat="server" AjaxCallConnection="Synchronous">
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" CssClass="button" ToolTip="gin." Text="LogIn" OnClick="btnTest_Click"></asp:Button>
        </ajax:AjaxPanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MagicAjax.UI;
using MagicAjax;

namespace -.-.-
{
    public partial class LoTest : AjaxPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AjaxCallHelper.WriteAlert("Test msg");
        }
    }
}
```

The web.config:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="MagicAjaxModule" type="MagicAjax.MagicAjaxModule, MagicAjax"/>
</httpModules>
```

In the Line “AjaxCallHelper.WriteAlert("Test msg");” throws the error:

Using the AjaxCallHelper write methods outside of an AjaxCall is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, just add the site to the compatibility view and that´s all.
Seems like if AjaxMagix.dll works with older elements of the explorer.

In Google Chrome doesn´t work.